# Laravel & Ajax: Send specific url to get data?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

i'm working with Laravel and Ajax to get data via urls,i have this one:

`Route::get('providers/{providers}','ProvidersController@getProviders');`

That function on my controller returns me all providers of an specific id, this works fine, but i need to populate this data in my select input, i'm currently getting it like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('#providers_types_id').change(function(event){
  $.get("providers/"+event.target.value+"",function(response,provider){
    $('#providers_id').empty();
    for(i=0; i<response.length; i++){
      $("#providers_id").append("<option value='"+response[i].id+"'>"+response[i].company+"</option>");
    }
    });
  });
});
```

So, i'm having troubles sending the url to get data, i need to send this:

```
http://myapp.local/providers/1
```

But i don't know why it's sending the currently url concatenated with my url:

```
http://myapp.local/prices/3/providers/1
```

Obviously i got 404 error, how i can send only the first url to get my data?
Sorry for my bad english !

Comment: No, i tried a lot but idk it's concatenating my url with the currently http://myapp.local/prices/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add a "/" at the start of url

```
$.get("/providers/"+event.target.value+"",function(response,provider){
    $('#providers_id').empty();
    for(i=0; i<response.length; i++){
      $("#providers_id").append("<option value='"+response[i].id+"'>"+response[i].company+"</option>");
    }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Wow ! it works like a charm ! thank u so much i dont knew that it was so simple

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution for you would be naming your route

```
Route::get('providers/{providers}','ProvidersController@getProviders')->name('anything');
```

And in your js file just before the $.get() put the following url variable

```
var url = '{{ route('anything', ['providers'=>'']) }}'+'/'+event.target.value;
```

Then use this url in $.get()

```
$.get(url, function(response,provider){ 

    // Your code ... 

});
```